# Cocoa - Reference a KEY in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, cocoa, key, nsdictionary

I want to referenciate a ket and not what it contains on a NSDictionary like this:

```
key {
    14819 =     {
        contactDetails =         {
            dictionary =             {
                interests =                 {
                    Movies =   
      ...
```

I want to make something like this:

```
if([key isEqualToString:@"14819"]){
 do something
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use allkeys method in nsdictionary to get keys array than iterate it to compare! like this:

```
NSArray*keys=[dict allKeys];
for(NSString *key in keys) {
    if ([key compare@"14819"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could send the array a `containsObject:` message (see AJak's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to look it up with the allKeys. Wrote a simple example, hope this helps.

```
NSMutableDictionary *testDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[testDictionary setObject:@"value" forKey:@"testObject"];

BOOL containsKey = [[testDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"testObject"];

NSLog(@"testing %d" ,containsKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test whether the key is present in the dictionary, use `objectForKey:` and test whether the object is not `nil`.

Getting `allKeys` and searching it for the key will work, but is almost certainly slower. Dictionaries are hash tables; `objectForKey:` uses that fact, whereas `allKeys` doesn't.

Comment: Another problem that I have with NSDictionarys is that it comes from a json response service, and sometimes some fields como equal to <null> and the app just crash!

Comment: @fabiosantos: What do you mean by “field”? If the key is present in the dictionary and the object describes as “`<null>`”, that is an NSNull object, and you can test for that.